# Auto sorting my data based on whether the job is closed and when it was closed

Tags: excel, vba

I have been wracking my brain over this one for quite a while now, I am trying to automate a work-task tracker as much as possible and I have hit a wall. It is a simple cut and paste macro; but I am trying to add a variable that might be getting thrown off by a formula in my spreadsheet. Basically I'd like the macro to look at column "F" and if it is "Closed" and if Column "G" has "Dec" (or "Jan" etc) then it will cut and paste to the corresponding sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Dim Check As Range, r As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastrow As Long, theDate As Date
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 lastrow = Worksheets("Master list").UsedRange.Rows.Count
 lastrow2 = Worksheets("Dec").UsedRange.Rows.Count
 If lastrow2 = 1 Then lastrow2 = 0
For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    If Range("F" & r).Value = "Closed" And Range("G" & r).Value = "Dec" Then
        Rows(r).Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Dec").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1) ' And here
    lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
    Else:
    End If
   Next r

Dim i As Long
Dim DelRange As Range

On Error GoTo Whoa


For i = 1 To 250
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & i & ":" & "Z" & i)) = 0 Then
        If DelRange Is Nothing Then
            Set DelRange = Rows(i)
        Else
            Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, Rows(i))
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete Shift:=xlUp
LetsContinue:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
 Exit Sub
Whoa:
 MsgBox "Perfectly balanced, as all things should be."
End Sub
```

- Ries